# Do we stop when we found one goal of many ones in trees?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, standards

If I have a tree of nodes that have two goals, for example. And I have to do a best-first search on it, which is an intelligent search that depends highly on the heuristic values of tree nodes.

So if I reached one of the two goals, do I stop the search as the goal is found, or do I continue until I find all the goals in the tree?

I want to know the **standard approach** in case the question didn't specify anything about that.

Also, suppose the question has meaningless nodes, not as the *Travelling Salesman* example.

---

This is the tree I'm intending although I'm asking in general:

### [image]

Comment: Best first refer to the order of the traverse - I guess all goal should be reached but it has nothing to do with best-first or DFS or BFS...

Comment: You have a point; I have edited my question.

Comment: There isn't really a standard approach, nor any way to determine what to do on an abstract tree. If you had a concrete problem this would either be part of the problem statement, you would be expected to infer it from the problem statement, or you would have to ask for clarification. If this is just a thought exercise it is up to you to determine what you want to do.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer | Then I guess I have to ask for clarifications since the question didn't mention anything about the goals except the fact that they are goals.